# How to get all contacts (sender, to, cc, etc) from a specific email using Outlook REST API with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, office365api, outlook-restapi

I need to get all the contacts involved in a specific email (sender, to, cc, etc) then access to their job title, company, primary and mobile phone numbers using Outlook Rest API 2.0 with JavaScript.

I got the token and everything and so far I've been successful in getting all contacts using this:

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts

But I don't want all contacts from the whole mailbox, I just want the contacts from a specific email and get the data described above.

Any ideas on how to achieve this will be appreciated A LOT!!

Thanks in advance guys!!

Answer (score 0):

checkout the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#get-messages

Response from the API has the sender object which has Sender, From, ToRecipients, CcRecipients, BccRecipients, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response Harisudhan! Indeed I can access those contacts from there, but the only data you can get is the email address and the contact name. What I need is to access those contacts Job Title, Company, Mobile and Primary Number. That's the problem.

Comment: Can you try Azure AD graph API, which is actually returns the user specific properties like job title, company etc..